# How can I fix my Minecraft on MacOS after accidentally removing folder?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8, and I deleted my Minecraft folder in `user/Library/Application Support` and now Minecraft will not run. I still have my saves folder, but when I tried to make a new Minecraft folder and put the saves folder back into it, Minecraft still would not run.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using "Force update"?

Comment: "Force update" should actually work. It basically formats and re-downloads your minecraft stuff. (from the launcher, before logging in)

Comment: I can't open the launcher. I click on the Minecraft icon on my desktop and nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

You can open your Minecraft launcher and click "Options", then click "Force Update". Then log in to Minecraft and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you save the launcher to the desktop or is it a shortcut?  If it's a shortcut, find where the launcher lives.  Delete it and redownload it from minecraft.net.  Start it and force update.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with the launcher.  The launcher will launch even if there is no minecraft folder.  I would:

- Delete your old minecraft launcher.
- Download a new launcher from http://minecraft.net/download.
- Make sure to backup your saves!
- Delete your `minecraft` (or `.minecraft` on Windows and Linux) folder.
- Open up your newly downloaded launcher.
- Click `Options`.
- Click `Force Update`.
- Now log into Minecraft normally.
- Close Minecraft.
- Copy your saves folder into your `minecraft` (or `.minecraft` on Windows and Linux) folder.

If you have any problems, make sure you have the latest version of Java installed.  I know 10.5.8 cannot get Java 7, but Minecraft will run on Java 6.

Another possibility is that you have a PowerPC (PPC) processor.  Computers with a PPC processor cannot run Java 6, and are stuck on Java 5.  Minecraft is discontinuing support for Java 5.  The changes are planned for Minecraft 1.6, however.